# SharePoint online list to raise a ticket

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, script-editor-webpart, list-form-web-part, spcascadedropdowns

I'm trying to create a list to raise a ticket, it contains multiple drop down list. As for SharePoint online I'm unable to use form web parts, in order to use content editor or script editor for SPservices to join Parent-Child column relationship. Is there any other option to create multiple drop-down list where the second drop-down list options depends upon the previous list's selected option ?

Answer (score 0):

If possible please check if you can use Power Apps to create customized forms for your list.

Details on SharePoint customized Power Apps forms can be found in this Microsoft knowledge article.

It is possible to use cascading in Power Apps forms.

Comment: I did used PowerApps for the cascading drop-down list and it worked but then there was issue, I was unable to save the form.

Comment: What was the actual error you have received? Can you share a screen shot? This is the preferred way to go for your problem. SharePoint content editor webpart is not available for modern pages and editing master pages is also not recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to create multiple drop-down list where the second drop-down list options depends upon the previous list's selected option, you can create cascading dropdown in SharePoint Online using jQuery.

Cascading dropdown in SharePoint 2013/2016/Online using jQuery for your reference:

https://www.sharepointsky.com/cascading-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-jquery/